# Pyro: Is it possible to pass a class from a server to a client and then instantiate an instance of that class on the client side?

Tags: python, remote-server, remoteobject, pyro

High level overview:
I have a `server.py` file and a class `WorkTask.py` that has some function `execute` in it, both stored on my server. I also have a `client.py` that runs remotely and connects to the server using pyro. Is there anyway that I can pass the `WorkTask` class from the server to the client and then run the `WorkTask.execute()` function on the client side?

Comment: Do you want the client's CPU to run the `WorkTask.execute()`, or do you want the server's CPU to run it but just have the client execute it?

Answer (score 1):

Only if you have a copy of WorkTask.py on the client already, and are using the pickle serializer.

You could also perhaps look at Pyro4.utils.flame.createModule(). See https://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/flame.html

It's a big security risk though because using pickle allows for arbitrary code execution if you connect to an untrusted remote party.